# how to add the custom format for price in php

Tags: php

I have price like this

212500

Expected output

2,125.00

what i have tried is below

```
<?php
$num ='212500';
//setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"en_US");
//echo money_format("The price is %i", $num);
$amount = '212500';
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN');
$amount = money_format('%!i', $amount);
echo $amount;

//echo $formattedNum = number_format($num, 2, ',', '');
```

Comment: you have changed the value itself.

Comment: can u please tell mw how to achieve this ?

Comment: what if the number is like 212501.

Comment: will come like this 2,125.01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your requirement you can do this .`first divide the number by 100 and then change the format`:

```
$amount = 212501;
echo number_format($amount/100, 2, '.', ',');//2,125.01
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use given method**

```
    function moneyformat($amount)
    {
        $amount = trim($amount);
        $amount = $amount/100;
        return number_format($amount, 2, '.', ',');
    }
$amount = 212500;
echo moneyformat($amount); //Output is 2,125.00
$amount = 212501;
echo moneyformat($amount); //Output is 2,125.01
```

Comment: can u please check my expected output